# ColdFusion query get current row values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfquery

I have a query that can return multiple records. I have two columns in my query, one column outputs the date values and second column is the type. I want to check the type of the each row and output the dates in the list. My current code for some reason outputs all date values in the same input field and that's not what I want. Here is my code:

```
<cfquery name="getUserRec" datasource="MyDBone">
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), u_begDt, 101) AS u_begDt, u_type    
    FROM Users WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE u_uid = <cfqueryparam value="#uid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="15">
        AND u_type IN ('A','C','M','S')
</cfquery>
```

Query will produce records like this:

```
u_begDt     u_type
03/16/2017    A 
03/01/2017    C 
03/01/2017    S
03/16/2017    M
02/01/2013    S
07/16/2015    A
```

Now I would like to output these record in 4 separate input fields:

```
<cfoutput>
   <input type="hidden" name="begDtA" id="begDtA" value="<cfif trim(getUserRec.u_type) EQ 'A'>#ValueList(getUserRec.u_begDt,",")#</cfif>" readonly="readonly" />
   <input type="hidden" name="begDtC" id="begDtC" value="<cfif trim(getUserRec.u_type) EQ 'C'>#ValueList(getUserRec.u_begDt,",")#</cfif>" readonly="readonly" />
   <input type="hidden" name="begDtM" id="begDtM" value="<cfif trim(getUserRec.u_type) EQ 'M'>#ValueList(getUserRec.u_begDt,",")#</cfif>" readonly="readonly" />
   <input type="hidden" name="begDtS" id="begDtS" value="<cfif trim(getUserRec.u_type) EQ 'S'>#ValueList(getUserRec.u_begDt,",")#</cfif>" readonly="readonly" />
</cfoutput>
```

My current code will output all date values in the same hidden field, looks that my cfif statements are ignored/incorrect. If anyone see where is my problem or different way to approach this problem please let me know.

Comment: If you really need a single field for each type, try using a grouped output. Though why not just generate multiple fields with each of those names? That will produce the desired CSV lists on the action page.  Also, which DBMS?

Comment: Can you provide any example how that should look like?

Comment: Which one? Do you actually need a single form field for each type or to have a single list of values for each type on the action page?

Comment: I need separate input field for each type that will hold the list of the date values for that type. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need to pre-populate the fields with a *list* of values or just produce that result on the action page?

If you just need to produce that result, then no need to do anything special. Simply create multiple fields with the same name. The result will be a csv list for each type on the action page.

```
<cfoutput query="getUserRec">
    <input type="text" name="begDt#getUserRec.u_type#"  
         value="#dateFormat(getUserRec.u_begDt, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#" />
</cfoutput>
```

If you really do need to pre-populate the fields with a list of values, use a grouped `cfoutput`. Modify your database query to `order by u_type`. (No need to format the dates in SQL. Leave that to the front end code). Then use a grouped cfoutput to build a list of values for each u_type.

```
<cfoutput query="getUserRec" group="u_type">
    <cfset dates = []>
    <cfoutput>
        <cfset arrayAppend(dates, dateFormat(getUserRec.u_begDt, "mm/dd/yyyy"))>
    </cfoutput> 
    <input type="text" name="begDt#getUserRec.u_type#" value="#arrayToList(dates)#" />
</cfoutput>
```

**Result:**

```
BEGDTA  03/01/2015,03/16/2017
BEGDTC  03/01/2017
BEGDTM  03/16/2017
BEGDTS  02/01/2013,03/01/2017
```

Comment: Since I have to validate/compare the dates for each u_type in JavaScript I think second solution will be better option. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You might try something more like this...

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="getUserRec">
  <cfif trim(u_type) EQ 'A'>
    <input type="hidden" name="begDtA" id="begDtA" value="#ValueList(u_begDt,",")#" readonly="readonly" />
  </cfif>
  <cfif trim(u_type) EQ 'C'>
    <input type="hidden" name="begDtC" id="begDtC" value="#ValueList(u_begDt,",")#" readonly="readonly" />
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: (Typo edit) ValueList() will still populate the hidden fields with all values.

Comment: That's correct, I still get all values in one hidden.

Comment: My above answer is NOT the answer I actually provided. This answer doesn't answer the question. Please disregard it.

Comment: (Edit) @EvikJames - You are right! Sorry, about that. When I viewed the original code, the CFML was not indented enough and was invisible. So I went to fix it and remove a redundant cfloop/cfouput. You probably fixed the indenting during the grace period. However, I can see the end result of my edit is *totally* different than what you actually posted. My bad! Must have pasted the wrong code from the clipboard. Anyway, I rolled back my bad edit.